# Select Count Cross tab in stored procedure SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a view name vStudent (Room_No, Study_Date, Student_ID, Student Sex, Nationality)
I want to create a stored procedure in SQL Server by scenario below:

i have some data:

- Room_No (1,2,3,4,..)
- Study_Date (08-02-2012,..)
- Student_ID (001,002,003,...)
- Student_Sex(Male, Female)
- Nationality(Cambodian, Thailand, Chinese)

in my stored procedure i want to:

- Select Room_No
- Select Study_Date
- Select Count Student_Sex separated by Male and Female
- Select Count Nationality separated by Cambodian, Thailand, Chinese
- Group BY Room_No, Study_Date
- Filter between Study_Date

the result in report should be show as below:

```
Room No Study Date  Male    Female  Cambodian   Thailand    Chinese
1   2/7/2012    1   0   1   0   0
2   2/8/2012    0   2   0   1   1
3   2/9/2012    1   2   1   2   0
4   2/10/2012   3   1   2   1   1
```

I think this can be done by use cross tab in stored procedure, but i don't know to do.

Please help. thanks.

Comment: You want the Student_ID on a row, but then you also want the count of how many nationalities and genders are represented by that student? Perhaps you can show some sample data and desired results. Your bullet list is not very clear.

Comment: Thanks, the Student_ID can be deleted from stored procedure.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron: your bullet list is contradictory. Please show a sample of the output you're looking for.

Comment: i've update my Question, pls kindly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to use dynamic SQL to figure out which columns you want to display, unless you know the full set of possible nationality values.

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME;

SET @start = '20120802';
SET @end = '20120802';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SELECT Room_No, Study_Date, 
    Male = SUM(CASE WHEN Student_Sex = ''Male'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Female = SUM(CASE WHEN Student_Sex = ''Female'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)';

SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
    ',' + Nationality + ' = SUM(CASE WHEN Nationality = ''' 
    + Nationality + ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)' 
FROM dbo.vStudent 
WHERE Nationality IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Nationality;  

SET @sql = @sql + ' FROM dbo.vStudent
    WHERE Study_Date >= ''' 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @start, 112) + '''
    AND Study_Date < ''' 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, 1, @end), 112) + '''
    GROUP BY Room_No, Study_Date;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If the set of nationalities is known, then you can simply say:

```
SELECT 
    Room_No, Study_Date, 
    Male      = SUM(CASE WHEN Student_Sex = 'Male'      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Female    = SUM(CASE WHEN Student_Sex = 'Female'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Cambodian = SUM(CASE WHEN Nationality = 'Cambodian' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Chinese   = SUM(CASE WHEN Nationality = 'Chinese'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Thailand  = SUM(CASE WHEN Nationality = 'Thailand'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    -- continue other nationalities here 
FROM dbo.vStudent
WHERE Study_Date >= @start
AND Study_Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @end)
GROUP BY Room_No, Study_Date;
```

You could probably do this a little more elegantly with `PIVOT`, but it really depends on your definition of "elegant." See the [docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, full set of nationality is known. it was limited. anyway when I execute it error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '='.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: Is it possible you have any NULL values for nationality?

Comment: I tried the second proc; it worked. many thanks Aaron Bertand.